# JavaScript - немного магии

Tags: javascript

Я новичек в js, при реализации загрузки картинки в <img />, через <input type="file" /> возник вопрос.

Задача состояла в том, что бы проверить, выбрал ли пользователь картинку разрешенного формата.

Я делал так:

```
document.getElementById("InputFile").onchange = function (){
if(this.value.match(/[^\.]{3,4}$/).match(/^jpeg|jpg|png|bmp|gif$/i))
    // ...
else
    return false;
```

}

Т.е. вроде синтаксических ошибок нет. Но скрип не собирался работать.
Данная строчка `this.value.match(/[^\.]{3,4}$/)` возвращает последние 3-4 символа, до точки (т.е. само расширение), а из возвращаемого значения проверял входит ли эта подстрока в массив перечисленных (jpeg|jpg|png|bmp|gif).

Думаю все логично...

Немного поэкспериментировав, добавил к строчке `this.value.match(/[^\.]{3,4}$/)` - прибавил пустую строку, дыбы преобразовать ее в строку.

Вот что вышло:

```
document.getElementById("InputFile").onchange = function (){
if((this.value.match(/[^\.]{3,4}$/) + "").match(/^jpeg|jpg|png|bmp|gif$/i))
    // ...
else
    return false;
```

}

Теперь все прекрасно работает, вопрос:

Почему до этого ничего не работало? Ведь `this.value.match(/[^\.]{3,4}$/)` и так нам будет возвращать строку?

Что то не понимаю в чем проблема была...

Answer (score 1):

`match()` возвращает массив результатов или null, внимательно читайте доки по js.

Comment: Спасибо, допустим он возвращает массив значений (если они есть), то обычным сложением строки можно массив преобразовать в строку?

Т.е. 

var q = (["Test 0", "Test 1", "Test 2"]) + "";

переменная q будет преобразована в строку на подобии q = (["Test 0", "Test 1", "Test 2"]).split("");  ?

Comment: Или что я не понял?

Comment: Откройте консоль и попробуйте.
`["1","2","3"] + "4" => "1,2,34"`